# Use path relative to @src in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

On an Angular 7 application I have the following:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "core-js/es7/reflect": ["../../node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"],
      "core-js/es6/*": ["../../node_modules/core-js/es/*"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

On a component I have the following:

```
import { environment } from '@src/environments/environment';
```

But when I build the application I get the error:

```
Cannot find module '@src/environments/environment'.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig.json add

```
  "baseUrl": "./",
```

Then remove baseUrl in your tsconfig.app.json

Then make sure restart angular cli then run again